# Cannot read property success of undefined

Tags: angular

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] HomeComponent.html:1
```

console.log(userDetail); gets this https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1AMB.png

The app compiles successfully and In the Home Component HTML it correctly prints the first_name but the console still shows the error which I mentioned above.

HTML file

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
{{userDetail.success.first_name}}
</div>
```

Typescript file

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.chk.checkLogin();
    this.chk.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe( (val) => {
      if(val) {
      this.isLoggedIn=val;
      }
    })

     //get user profile
     this.chk.getUserProfile().subscribe((res: any)=> {
      this.userDetail = res;
      console.log(this.userDetail);
      });
```

AuthService file

```
   //Get User Profile
   getUserProfile() {
    return this.http.post(this.userProfileApi, null);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are getting the profile from an asynchronous request, the error will be thrown as the data is not available , you could handle it with a **`safe navigation operator`** (?) as follows

```
<h2 *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
  {{userDetail?.success?.first_name}}
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a safe operator, e.g. `{{userDetail?.success?.first_name}}`. That should handle it